# Auto-collapsing fieldsets on user_profile_form

Tags: 7, forms, users

I am following these guides:
Customize the User Edit page in Drupal 7: https://www.drupal.org/node/2279959
Collapsing default fieldsets (Drupal 6): https://www.drupal.org/node/733198

Basically, I just want to make all of the fieldsets on the user_profile_form (e.g. /user/1/edit) collapsed by default.

Here is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work - page never finishes loading (I have changed THEMENAME to the name of my theme).  This still doesn't work however...

```
function THEMENAME_theme() {
  return array(
    // The form ID.
    'user_profile_form' => array(
      // Forms always take the form argument.
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}

function THEMENAME_user_profile_form($form) {
  //Create array to return
  $form_elements = element_children($form);
  foreach ($form_elements as $element) {
    //Identify fieldsets and collapse them
    if ($form[$element]['#type'] == 'fieldset') { 
      $form[$element]['#collapsible'] = TRUE;
      $form[$element]['#collapsed']   = TRUE;
    }
  }
  return drupal_render($form);
}
```

I have a feeling that there is something that I am missing regarding converting this Drupal 6 code to work with Drupal 7 but I am lost.  I have about 30 tabs open and have searched extensively on stackexchange, drupal.org, etc. to no avail.  Please help!

EDIT: here is the code for a small custom module I wrote to easily test this (no need to clear the cache every time like with template.php)

```
function collapse_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == "user_profile_form")
    {
        $form['edit-picture']['#collapsible'] = true;
        $form['edit-picture']['#collapsed'] = true;
       $form['edit-timezone']['#collapsible'] = true;
        $form['edit-timezone']['#collapsed'] = true;
        // test to make sure module and hook_form_alter is working
        $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'foo7';
    }
}
```

I should add that I've tried dashes and underscores, e.g. edit_picture and edit-picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to figure out an answer to this.  Thanks to Scott Joudry for helping me through this and giving me a lot of ideas.  Eventually I got to this code, written in a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules) (this is the entire contents of my 'collapse.module' file):

```
<?php
// we use MODULENAME_form_FORMID_alter to restrict it to the specific form
// this helps reduce processing time, as Drupal will ignore this on any other forms
function collapse_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    // can't hurt to double-check that we're on the right form
    if ($form_id == "user_profile_form")
    {
         // Note that the ID of the fieldset is "picture" not "edit-picture" like
         // the fieldset's HTML ID - you may have to guess-and-check to find it.
         // Usueally you remove the "edit-" part of the HTML ID, and replace any
         // spaces with underscores, i.e. "edit-signature-settings"
         // becomes "signature_sttings"
         // Only these two lines are needed if the fieldset you are trying 
         // to collapse is not collapsible by default, such as the user picture.
         $form['picture']['#collapsible'] = true;
         $form['picture']['#collapsed'] = true;

         // A third line is needed if the fieldset you are trying to collapse
         // is collapsible, but is uncollapsed by default - for example, the timezone.
         // Note that depending on the fieldset, this third line MAY OR MAY NOT
         // be needed! Start without it, and if the fieldset isn't collapsing,
         // add the third line to force the addition of the 'collapsed' class.
         $form['timezone']['#collapsible'] = true;
         $form['timezone']['#collapsed'] = true;
         $form['timezone']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'collapsed';

         // Implement an "after_build" to put these changes into the form.
         // The array is just which function you are telling it to run.
        $form['#after_build'] = array('collapse_fieldsets');

         // Test to make sure module and hook_form_alter is working 
         // and the page hasn't been cached - very easy to check if the 
         // main form's class has been updated each time you refresh.
         // Just change the version number each time you upload this .module file.
        $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'version-5';
    }
}

// this function renders the form content
function collapse_fieldsets($form_element, &$form_state) 
{
        // Note that this is the same as above, but with $form_element instead of $form.
        // Everything you put in the above code must be duplicated here.
        $form_element['picture']['#collapsible'] = true;
        $form_element['picture']['#collapsed'] = true;

        $form_element['timezone']['#collapsible'] = true;
        $form_element['timezone']['#collapsed'] = true;
        $form_element['timezone']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'collapsed';

        return $form_element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) here.

```
THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == "user_profile_form")
    {
        $form["FIELDSET"]["#collapsible"] = true;
        $form["FIELDSET"]["#collapsed"] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this code in my template.php, and unfortunately it doesn't work - with or without the first function that I posted.  I double-checked the site and the user profile does indeed have the form ID "user_profile_form" but nothing so far.  Tried clearing the cache twice as well.  Can't think of why this wouldn't work...?

Comment: are you logged in as the admin? And if so, is your admin theme different than the theme you are trying to modify? If yes, go to /admin/appearance and set the admin theme accordingly.

Comment: Yep, using the same theme for admin - the site is definitely reading the template.php, because if I make a typo in the code, I get a white-screen error message ;-)  It seems like Drupal does not like form_alter being used on the user_profile_form.  I have tried changing it to [profile_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!profile!profile.module/function/profile_form_alter/7) and [hook_form_form_id_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) but with no success.

Comment: Update: I made a custom module with your code, and the additional line `$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'foo';`.  Indeed, it does add the class 'foo' to the user_profile_form.  So, it's working, but there is something wrong with the two lines you wrote to collapse the fieldsets.  I am reading the Form API for Drupal 7 but I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: "FIELDSET" was an example and wont exist, you need to replace it with the id of the fieldset you are trying to collapse.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the fieldset id's (gathered from the HTML - I'm assuming there is no 'machine name' ID) but no change.  I edited the first post above to show my module code.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, it's working for me :)